# Font configuration on Linux dual-head configuration with DPI's at 90 and 150:

Tags: linux, fonts, display, dpi

I have a laptop with a 15" screen and a resolution of 1920 X 1200 and a 22" external monitor running at 1680 X 1050.

This means the laptop runs with a dpi of 150 and the monitor runs at a dpi of 90.  Is there anyway to get the fonts on the laptop to be readable while keeping the fonts on the monitor from being gigantic?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Set the DPI to be somewhere inbetween the two settings, so it just appears a little too big on the monitor, and a little too small on the laptop
- Move the laptop monitor closer to your face so the fonts appear larger.
- Buy a new external monitor with a higher DPI

Comment: Well this is at work so I don't have much of an option to change hardware.  The other two I've though about but aren't really very good solutions. I was hoping that there was some way to essentially downgrade the resolution on the laptop screen without making it all blurry.